# What are these symbols called? ~ ` ^

Tags: single-word-requests, punctuation, symbols, diacritics

What can I call the following symbols?

## ~

## `

## ^

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time - you are asking three separate questions here.

Comment: Also, can you add some context to this request? These characters are not used in normal English writing.

Comment: How does this question relate to English language and usage?

Comment: @Hugo: It's actually three single word requests.  I see nothing wrong with it other than that it is three questions in one.

Comment: Although it is difficult to enter symbols like these in Google or other search engines, you can often search for them in references like [Wikipedia](http://www.wikipedia.org/); they return the pages @drɱ65 δ has mentioned in the answer below.

Comment: I don't understand the votes to close. We're always getting questions like *"What's the word for [ddescription of something]?"*. This one is as good as it gets! @Gimp has actually given us *the exact somethings* he wants the names of. No need to keep asking for clarification about exactly what his "something" is!

Comment: @Fumble: And you can also type those exact somethings into Wikipedia and get their names--general reference.

Comment: @simchona: Ah, well I wouldn't have expected to be able to do that. Most search boxes I'm used to don't support such characters in the lookup. It's answered here anyway, so I suppose it's academic.

Comment: The second one is also often called a "back quote".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**~** is a [tilde](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde).

**^** is a [caret](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret).

**`** is a [grave accent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent) when used as an accent or a [backtick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent#Use_in_programming), when used alone.

Comment: I've heard ~ (tilde) referred to as *wiggle* and *twiddle* in numerous math lectures.  Ordinarily, a given lecturer only uses one term or the other and is consistent.  The common word for ^ (caret) in math lectures is *hat* and in LaTex it's obtained by __\hat__.

Comment: @jwpat7: Good grief! - *wiggle, twiddle, hat?*. I suppose those maths teachers were too busy learning numbers to learn letters.

Comment: @fum, none of those are 'letters'

Comment: @whoabackoff: True, but I'd still classify such teachers as "unlettered", even though I've no doubt they'd all at least know the alphabet. I find it particularly depressing that jwpat7's reference to "math lectures" implies we're talking about reasonably advanced maths teaching here, where *tildes* and *carets* are common symbols.

Comment: @fum, it's not uncommon for symbols to go by different names in mathematics: exclamation mark for factorials, slash for division, colon for ratios, full stops for decimal points... even symbols like the asterisk and number signs go by different names in math. I find this in no way depressing, and would never classify these professors as "unlettered".

Answer (score 3):

- ~ - this is a tilde
- ^ - this is a caret
- ` - and this is a backtick