# What is the third 'quote' (inverted comma) called?

Tags: punctuation, diacritics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are these symbols called?  ~  `  ^](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43166/what-are-these-symbols-called)

Most of use are familiar with `"` and `'` but what is the third ` (same key as ~ on a standard US keyboard) character called, and how or when is it to be used?

I'm thinking that this might simply be a computer only character but I'd like to be sure.

Comment: It is a duplicate indeed, I don't have the ability to close a dup.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/b/backquot.htm) it's called either a *back quote*, *acute*, *grave*, *grave accent*, *left quote*, *open quote*, or a *push*. See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent) for its uses in foreign languages to show stress, pitch, and more.

Comment: I've always referred to the character on its own as a *backtick*.

Comment: Backtick?  Are you in England?