# How can I call these symbols in English?

Tags: symbols, diacritics

I'm a programmer and I wonder how I can call these symbols in English:

- ~
- |
- ^
- `

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are these symbols called?  ~  `  ^](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43166/what-are-these-symbols-called)

Comment: Three of those symbols, ~^` (tilde, caret, grave accent) are covered in a [now-closed question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43166/what-are-these-symbols-called).  (Closed as off-topic.) Names of all of these, including the vertical bar, or pipe, can be found in a [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_bar) article.

Comment: @jwpat Not an exact duplicate because | is here, but that question was closed as off-topic. Also, if you search for each character in Google, you get the corresponding Wikipedia pages: general reference. So, definitely shows no research (downvote) and a vote to close (general reference if not off-topic).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They have some other names (such as "grave accent" for `), but these are the most common in programming:

- ~ [tilde](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde)
- , [comma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma)
- | [bar or pipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_bar)
- ^ [caret](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret)
- ` [backtick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtick)