# How to pronounce the ^ symbol?

Tags: pronunciation, symbols

How should the "^" symbol be pronounced? I searched on the internet but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Are you asking about a symbol which stands alone, or one in combination with a letter (eg ô)? [Although, I suppose, a good answer will include both]

Comment: It depends on context.  It's a *caret*, a *hat*, the *exponentiation* ("raised to") symbol, or one of several others, depending on how it's being used.

Comment: @Hot Licks, that should be an answer.

Comment: As a programmer, I pronounce it _XOR_.

Comment: **Ahem** It's _obviously_ pronounced ["Kakarot"](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Kakarot)!

Comment: In lay man language it could be pronounced as "Cap"

Comment: I'd go with *caret*, as a safe default, unless you’re using it for a specific purpose (in which case you might call it a circumflex, a hat, the exponentiation symbol, and so on).

Comment: `‸` is a caret. However, `^` is a circumflex.

Comment: It's called a "caret" and is pronounced exactly like "carrot".

Comment: @pipe Interesting. A mathematician might analogously call it *AND* (mathematical *OR* is the same shape inverted - I'm not aware of a mathematical symbol for *XOR*).

Comment: Duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43166/what-are-these-symbols-called

Comment: regardless of the context (power of, xor, ctrl+) I still always refer to it as a caret

Answer (score 91, accepted):

That looks like a caret symbol.

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret ...

> The **caret /ˈkærət/** is an inverted V-shaped grapheme.
>
> It is the spacing character **^** in ASCII  [...] and other character sets that may also be called a hat, control, uparrow, or less frequently chevron, xor sign, to the power of, pointer [...] or wedge.
>
> Officially, this character is referred to as circumflex accent in both ASCII and Unicode terminology (because of its historical use in overstrike), whereas caret refers to a similar but lowered Unicode character: U+2038 **‸** CARET.

From [Computer Desktop Encyclopedia](http://www.yourdictionary.com/caret) ...

> **caret** — The small up-facing arrow on the "6" key (shift-6) on a typewriter keyboard. Also called a "hat," it is used as a symbol for several different operations. The mathematical expression 2^12 means 2 to the 12th power. It is also used as an exclusive OR operator (see XOR), and it is sometimes found as a symbol for the Control key; for example, ^Y means Ctrl-Y.

[image: caret symbol on keyboard]

Comment: While it "looks" like a caret (pronounced /ˈkarət/), the [dictionary definition of caret](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/caret) is a mark "placed **below the line** to indicate a proposed insertion in a text" (my emphasis). The other answers given here demonstrate that there are many other words that might apply to the symbol - context (and location of the symbol on the line) mean everything!

Comment: Okay, have added more details on the subtleties.

Comment: Note Thomas' answer and the comments - technically this glyph is called a ***circumflex*** in the code pages, but *common usage* in American English is definitely to call it a ***caret***.

Comment: In Programming, where the `^` is often used, it is almost always referred to as a caret, except perhaps when it denotes exponentiation. The [Wikipedia Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) on ASCII characters also refers to it as a caret.

Comment: It is also used in French for certain words ( être ) - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_of_the_circumflex_in_French

Comment: @Chappo And this symbol *is* in fact often placed below the previous line, in order to point to something.

Comment: @hamstergene: umm, I'm not sure what you're getting at: isn't this what my cited definition says? But I dispute that it's "often" used that way. It's almost **never** used that way in non-technical printed literature. And as a diacritic (eg in Bakudan's example of *être*) it doesn't "point" to anything.

Comment: @Chappo How is it used in non-technical printed literature? I can't recall seeing it outside of smilies or pretend cartoon swearing.

Comment: I've heard this referred to as not just a caret, but also as an "up caret." I thought this was common usage, but after a Google, I'm not so sure.

Comment: @PeteKirkham: I said it's **not** generally used in non-technical printed literature! The dictionary meaning says it's used *below the line* like this: "dict‸onary". It's ***handwritten*** on a printed draft to show an error, eg. a letter missing. This particular use is therefore very rare in printed material of any kind, since no one would ever type the symbol, they'd simply fix the error. In non-technical literature, the "hat" is more likely to be appear as a *circumflex* diacritic. Eg: [raison d'être](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/raison-d%27etre?q=raison+d%27etre).

Comment: @Chappo no, you said it 'almost never used that way' in non-technical printed literature, which can be read as 'of the ways it is used in non-technical printed literature, it is almost never under the line'. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @Chappo Usage is of course not universal, but in my experience as a proofreader and editor, the character `U+2038 ‸ CARET` is **not** normally used to indicate a missing letter. That is reserved for `U+2041 ⁁ CARET INSERTION POINT`. The caret is used to indicate a missing _word_ (i.e., `‸` indicates that the addition written in the margin should be enclosed in spaces when inserted, whereas `⁁` indicates that the addition should be inserted _without_ added spaces). That’s in formalised proofreading, though; informally, you’ll find all sorts.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: thanks for the clarification, and yes I'd forgotten about electronic proofing/editing. My main point was that the U+2038 ‸ CARET does not normally appear in *published* non-tech documents.

Comment: @Chappo That much I was definitely agreeing with!

Answer (score 69):

As a diacritic, this symbol is a [**circumflex**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circonflex).

According to the linked Wikipedia article, **hat**, **roof** or **house** are used when the context is mathematics.

Comment: Indeed, this is the Unicode character U+005E: CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT.

Comment: True: "*Officially, this character is referred to as circumflex accent in both ASCII and Unicode terminology (because of its historical use in overstrike), whereas caret refers to a similar but lowered Unicode character: U+2038 ‸ CARET.*" In AmEnglish, when talking about the key on the keyboard, **caret** is extremely common, and most people would give a blank stare if asked to type a **circumflex** in a password, say. Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret

Comment: @ToddWilcox much the same way that the AmEnglish keyboards "have a backquote or backtick", but the Portuguese ones "have a [grave accent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent)" (and an acute one too); you'd get the same blank stares if you talked about a grave accent, I guess.

Answer (score 33):

The answer depends entirely on context.

If you're doing quantum mechanics, it's called a *hat* and signifies that the thing it's on top of is an operator (something that acts on a wave function to derive an eigenvalue).

If you're reading French, it's a *circumflex* and signifies a miniscule prononciation difference that only native French speakers can hear. Also, that there probably used to be an *s* after the thing it's on top of (e.g. *forêt* - forest).

Comment: And if you're doing math with a limited character set, it signifies exponentiation and is spoken as "to the" or "to the power of".

Comment: In computer science, this is called a hat.

Comment: Linguistics uses it as a modification (accent) on a character, or as a full space vowel character - [ʌ], the first vowel in _hunting_. The name of that symbol is also "caret", though Unicode thinks it's "small latin letter turned v" U+028C.

Comment: +1. This is the only answer that answers the question as written, which is about how to pronounce the character. (The other answers all provide *names* of the character, which is not the same thing: `&` is *named* "ampersand", but usually *pronounced* "and".)

Comment: @JohnLawler I've always known that symbol as "wedge".

Comment: _"a miniscule prononciation difference that only native French speakers can hear"_ I can hear it.

Comment: A useful link to perhaps include in the post: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_of_the_circumflex_in_French

Comment: Anyone who cannot hear the difference between French _notre_ [nɔtʁ] and _nôtre_ [noːtʁ] needs their ears checking. On the other hand, _sur_ ‘on’ and _sûr_ ‘sure’ are pronounced exactly the same, and not even native French speakers can hear any difference (even if some of them probably think they can). And in Paris (and Belgium), /ɑ/ and /a/ have basically merged, so _tâche_ ‘task’ and _tache_ ‘stain’ are pronounced the same, though elsewhere they’re still distinct. So to say that “only native French speakers can hear” the difference is quite incorrect, in both ‘directions’.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Oh dear... It's true what they say, it is impossible to convey humour in an internet forum.

Comment: And, while we're conveying humor, if you're reading French it's a circonflexe.

Answer (score 25):

A few symbols that look like ^:

- Well, ^ itself; in maths, I usually call it *hat*, but [another answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/333517/89715) says Wikipedia says it is also called *roof* or *house*; as a diacritic, I would call it a circumflex, or maybe even a hat; in French, it is called "accent circumflexe" (circumflex accent), or [le petit chapeau](http://www.200words-a-day.com/circumflex-in-french.html) (the little hat), so yeah, *hat* is just fine;
- There is the *caret*, which is technically the hat below the line (‸), though this is apparently [called by several other names too](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret);
- We have *turned v* (ʌ), IPA symbol for the vowel in *plus* (which is an open-mid back unrounded vowel), [also used in some languages' orthography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turned_v);
- We have the Greek capital lambda (Λ), which is, of course, read *lambda* or *big lambda* if there is a lowercase one referring to something else in a mathematical setting; this is totally unrelated to the turned v above;
- We have the *wedge* (∧), used for the [wedge product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra) (or exterior product) of differential forms in Differential Geometry, for the [wedge sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedge_sum) of topological spaces in topology, two cases where it is read *wedge*, and also as the [logical and](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction), where it is read, of course, *and*;
- The slightly different Unicode *n-ary logical and* (⋀), which is probably read *and*.

That should be all. Apparently, *caret* is the most common American pronunciation of the circumflex character ^ (says [this comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/333514/how-to-pronounce-the-symbol#comment762539_333517)). Note that ^ is used to mark the CONTROL KEY, in which case it is pronounced *control* (e.g., ^Y stands for Ctrl+Y, which you read *control-Y*).

Answer (score 3):

In the [INTERCAL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INTERCAL) programming language circa 1972, it's called [shark](http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/intercal-man/tonsila.html) or sharkfin.

For describing its appearance in ASCII (or other early character sets) rather than its *meaning* in any specific context (like "xor operator", "raise to power") and noting that it's *not* really the printer's caret as explained in another answer, *sharkfin* actually does a very good job of conveying which glyph to find, especially a non-tech person who has no idea what it's really called.

Comment: For those who don't know, INTERCAL (full name: _Compiler Language With No Pronounceable Acronym_) is, like, totally a serious representative for programming languages in general. Like, not.

Answer (score 2):

Mathematicians may be a different species but at any rate they pronounce it "upper", as in $x^i$: "x upper i". I am a mathematician professionally and this usage is very common among my colleagues.

Comment: I am currently looking for one (though this is common knowledge among this particular species).

Comment: An answer can rely on the specific expertise of the author. Describing that expertise should be part of the answer. Mikhail can you consider editing your answer. For example: "I am a mathematician and I and all of my colleagues use this pronunciation"