# What do you call the symbol used to insert word(s) into a sentence?

Tags: symbols

I have seen the example of the blue symbol in the picture in some advertisements. This symbol is used to add an extra word in the middle of a sentence. However, I have searched a lot, but I was not able to find the name of this symbol in English.

[image: The picture]

Comment: If placed below the line pointing upward, one could call it a [caret](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret).

Comment: Answered at [How should the ^ symbol be pronounced?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/333514/how-to-pronounce-the-symbol/333516#333516)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inverted caret symbol is sometimes named as [caron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caron), though this is in the context of a [diacritic mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic) rather than a proof reading mark.

Answer (score -1):

That is intended to mimic a proofreader's mark. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_proofreader%27s_marks#Symbols) this particular mark is a caret.

Comment: Is a caret not pointing upwards? Wikipedia only says _Caret|^/ v|Insert_, using a the letter V as a downwards arrow.

Comment: A caret indicates where something should be inserted. Traditionally, it points upwards, but an inverted version (pointing downward) is also used.

Comment: Could you add that, as well as a reference from a site that's not Wikipedia, to your question?